# $.get() gives error, on callback (?)

Tags: jquery, django, get

I know there are many questions like this, but I can't find the solution for my problem.

`MyScript.js`:

```
$('#id_tags').keyup(function(){
    var query;
    query = $(this).val();
    $.get('/blog/suggest-category/', {suggestion: query}, function(data){
      console.log('data')
      $('#suggestion_div').html(data);
    });
  });
```

My `view.py`:

```
def get_category_list(max_results=0, starts_with=''):
    print('get_category_list')
    cat_list = []
    if starts_with:
        cat_list = Tag.objects.filter(slug__istartswith=starts_with)
    if max_results > 0:
        if len(cat_list) > max_results:
            cat_list = cat_list[:max_results]
    return cat_list


def suggest_category(request):
    print('suggest_category')
    cat_list = []
    starts_with = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        starts_with = request.GET['suggestion']
        cat_list = get_category_list(5, starts_with)
    print('cat_list', cat_list)
    #return render(request, 'blog/suggest_tag.html', {'suggestions': cat_list })
    return cat_list
```

`query`, in `MyScript.js` is a string. The view is called (I can read the `print('cat_list', cat_list)`) but then it throw an error:

when the list is empty =>`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

when isn't (for example: `cat_list [<Tag: Home>]`) => `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Traceback error with cat_list empty:

```
cat_list []
Internal Server Error: /blog/suggest-category/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.
py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjac
king.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
[28/Dec/2017 16:25:08] "GET /blog/suggest-category/?suggestion= HTTP/1.1" 500 14
867
```

or with cat_list not empty:

```
cat_list [<Tag: Home>]
Internal Server Error: /blog/suggest-category/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.
py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjac
king.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 378, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query
.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query
.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query
.py", line 1146, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
[28/Dec/2017 16:08:23] "GET /blog/suggest-category/?suggestion=h HTTP/1.1" 500 1
5797
```

Maybe can help the TAG model, it comes from taggit:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TagBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), unique=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Slug'), unique=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.slugify(self.name)
            from django.db import router
            using = kwargs.get("using") or router.db_for_write(
                type(self), instance=self)
            # Make sure we write to the same db for all attempted writes,
            # with a multi-master setup, theoretically we could try to
            # write and rollback on different DBs
            kwargs["using"] = using
            # Be oportunistic and try to save the tag, this should work for
            # most cases ;)
            try:
                with atomic(using=using):
                    res = super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                return res
            except IntegrityError:
                pass
            # Now try to find existing slugs with similar names
            slugs = set(
                self.__class__._default_manager
                .filter(slug__startswith=self.slug)
                .values_list('slug', flat=True)
            )
            i = 1
            while True:
                slug = self.slugify(self.name, i)
                if slug not in slugs:
                    self.slug = slug
                    # We purposely ignore concurrecny issues here for now.
                    # (That is, till we found a nice solution...)
                    return super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                i += 1
        else:
            return super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def slugify(self, tag, i=None):
        slug = default_slugify(unidecode(tag))
        if i is not None:
            slug += "_%d" % i
        return slug


class Tag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")
        app_label = 'taggit'
```

Edit:
I changed my `view.py`:

```
def suggest_category(request):
    print('suggest_category')
    cat_list = []
    starts_with = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        starts_with = request.GET['suggestion']
        cat_list = get_category_list(5, starts_with)
    print('cat_list', cat_list)
    return render(request, 'blog/suggest_tag.html', {'suggestions': cat_list })
```

and here's my template `suggest_tag.html`:

```
{% load i18n %}

     <ul>
        {% if suggestions %}
            {% for c in suggestions %}
                <li>{{ c.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <li>{% trans "There are no tag present." %}</li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

Now it writes in a division that I create (`id='suggestion_div'`) so it works enough.

/edit

Comment: The back trace from Python world tell us where the error was, but you didn't include it.  I don't see a call to `.get` anywhere, did I miss it?

Comment: .get is called in the script at line 4 (but probably you are saying something else...) anyway Traceback added.

Comment: That's the JavaScript .get call, but you're getting a Python error

Comment: It certainly seems like you're passing a list to your ORM where it expects a dictionary.  I think it's where you call `Tag.objects.filter()`, but I can't turn that into a decent answer.

Comment: `type(cat_list)` = `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` before the return in `suggest_category`. TAG comes from taggit model, now I'll find and add to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are caused by returning something that is not an HttpResponse from your view.

It's not clear from the code exactly what you want to be sent to the JavaScript, but whatever it is it needs to be wrapped in an HttpResponse or a subclass of that. Perhaps you want to serialise a queryset?